# Pre-commit script creates mysqldump file, but "nothing to commit (working directory clean)"?

Tags: git

I'm using the script .git/hooks/pre-commit to take snapshots of a MySQL database along with other project files.  Here are the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u user -ppassword --skip-extended-insert dbname > /path/to/repo/dbname.sql
cd /mnt/hoste/Storage/Code/test-repo/
git add /path/to/repo/dbname.sql
```

If I run:

```
git commit -am "Message"
```

A new dump file is created, but then git tells me:

```
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Then, if I run the identical commit command again, it works:

```
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Then, if I run the identical command again, back to "nothing to commit".  This pattern continues ad infinitum - works, doesn't work, works, doesn't work.  It's not based on time (I've tried commit immediately, and waiting 10 minutes).  Mysqldump is certainly updating the .sql file (it date stamps them with hh:mm:ss format near the end of the file).

If I take the script, and run it line by line at the command line (including first cd'ing to the hooks directory to fully simulate running the script), there is a new commit every time.  If I put it in an executable file in hooks, or in repo root, and execute it from command line, and then run the commit command, it works every time.  It only doesn't work every other time, and then only when it's run from within pre-commit.

What could be causing this weird behaviour?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's generated afterwards - I have echoes, and other git statuses in the script for test purposes and the all happen before the built in status message.  Also the number of commits isn't being incremented on the non-working attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a hook, make sure to always specify the git_dir and work_tree:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/your/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/your/repo add -- yourFile
```

By changing folder in a hook, you are *not* changing what was the current git repo. If that repo is supposed to change, it is best to reference it explicitly with the `--git-dir` option.

Comment: I added that line to the top of my pre-commit script, and the behaviour is unchanged.  To be clear, everything is in the same repo; I'm not attempting to save the mysqldumps in their own repo.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall not on the top, in the git add line.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see.  But still though, no change.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall did you specified the path of the `.git` folder within the repo you want for `git-dir`? It is easy to miss the final `.git`. Make sure that path does exist (no typo). What version of git are you using?

Comment: yes, here is the actual line I'm using: git --git-dir=/mnt/hoste/Storage/Code/test-repo/.git --work-tree=/mnt/hoste/Storage/Code/test-repo/ add -- wptestsite.sql

Comment: @DuncanMarshall and if you ware to manually go to that repo, would that file be added (meaning, was it perhaps already added in that repo with your previous tests?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - the file is modified and added by pre-commit every time it's run, it's just that it is only recognized as having been changed every second time I run the commit command.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall is it possible this is some kind of synchronization issue (git doesn't yet recognize the modified file). Could you add a sleep for half a second just before the git add? (`sleep 0.5`, http://serverfault.com/a/469259/783)

Comment: Yeah, thought it was that at first.  Added large amounts of sleep, to no avail.  It's consistently a works/doesn't work pattern.  Also it works 100% of the time that I do this from a non-hook bash script that contains identical commands.  I wonder if it has something to do with git not wanting to add files that hooks make, but then I don't know why it would ever work, rather than just 50% of the time.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall what a `git status` would output in that hook? (especially in the 50% of the time where the `git add` doesn't work)

Comment: I put `git status` both at the top and bottom of the file.  On the time it *didn't* work, the top status command produces `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`, and the bottom produces `modified:   wptestsite.sql` but then the normal status message after that still claims the working directory is clean.  On the time it *does* work, the _top and bottom_ status messages both say "modified:   wptestsite.sql".

Comment: @DuncanMarshall wait... the bottom message should always state that the file isn't just modified, but added to the index. It should differ from the first status (when the first one works, I mean)

Comment: In both instances - working and non-working - it says:
`# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   wptestsite.sql
`
It's just that on the non-working times it then claims there is nothing to commit.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall so the `git add` *never works* (in the right order), since the `git status` *before* the `git add` already states "`change to be committed`". Can you try a `sleep 0.5` *after* the `git add` and before the second `git status`?

Comment: That last test already had `sleep 3.0` between `git add` and the last `git status`.  Still off-on working pattern.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall What Os version and git version are you using?

Comment: git version 1.7.10.4 on Debian 7

Comment: @DuncanMarshall any chance of trying the same, with a git a bit more recent? (git 2.1.0: http://superuser.com/a/683123/141)

Comment: Your link for updating to 2.1.0 yilded multiple errors.  Thanks anyway, but I think I'm just going to quit trying, and use some other method of doing this.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall I understand, but using a more recent version of git would be in general a good idea ;)

Comment: The version I'm running is the one installed by aptitude as of last night.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall then a quick sompilation from the sources could help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-debian-7

Comment: @DuncanMarshall I suppose it works better with a recent Git version, then?

Comment: I tried the DO method, it also failed.  Rather than troubleshoot it in order to use pre-commit, I just wrote a bash script to do the same thing.  It's not the best way, but can't throw any more hours at it.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

What I observe is that the "pre-commit" hook occurs after git has "frozen" the list of files to be affected (i.e., chosen a content addressable name of the repository state), and it cannot be influenced to alter that; instead, the "git add" in the pre-commit hook is making changes to the index that will be in effect once the commit is finished, and thus the *next* "git commit" shows the result of the "git add" within the pre-commit git hook.

A more comprehensive discussion is here: [Can one re-stage files in a pre-commit git hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899526/can-one-re-stage-files-in-a-pre-commit-git-hook)

In my attempts to do "git add" within my own pre-commit hook (I similarly wanted to automatically generate and "git add" some file(s) to my commit), I've tried various tricks with recursive calls to git-commit, but it all ends up being really ugly, and git making un-helpful complaints.  I'm going to abandon my hooks/pre-commit attempts, and instead use a shell alias that does "stuff && git add things && git commit".