# Github file exceed 100MB

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

I know there is many many threads about this but being a noob to coding I do not understand what the codes people reply with...
My issue is the file is too big. Now during hours of searching, I found a solution, Github's LFS. The issue is that I can't manage to activate it. As well as I tried making a new repository to upload my project (hoping it will take the entire project).

Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you attempting to push to GitHub that exceeds 100MB?

Comment: Working on a project in Unity

Comment: What type of file is it causing the issue, Images, musics, videos, etc?

Comment: Did you follow the steps on this site? https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: When saving a Unity project into Github we only save the Assets Folder and the ProjectSettings. Those are the two files i save.

Comment: I do not understand what the steps ask me to do. Like I mentioned I barely any notion on coding

Answer (score 0):

[Github have documented this and set up restrictions against pushing files over 100mb.](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/)

[And more info about it here](https://help.github.com/articles/conditions-for-large-files/)

It seems like there is no way around this. You'll need to either break up the file into smaller pieces or look for other alternatives.

Other users have mention this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34780618/3010171

I'm not sure if that fits your project.

Comment: How can I break the file into smaller pieces?

Comment: If it's models, you might add those into smaller projects and piece and 'include' them up in another file.. So the file just refers to other files.. Not sure if that works in what file type your file is.