# Can one re-stage files in a pre-commit git hook?

Tags: git, bash, powershell, github, githooks

I've made a powershell script that adds a header to certain files within my project. I want to run it whenever code is in the process of being pushed to GitHub so that all such files in the GitHub repository have the header attached, removing the need to run the script manually.

The issue is that when I modify the files in my pre-commit git hook, those changes aren't restaged, so I essentially have to stage, commit and then stage again for the headers to be committed.

Is there a good way to deal with this, or is it better practice to separate the execution of that powershell script from the git flow?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

The answer to the question in the subject line is "yes, but." :-)  I'll rephrase it a bit here so that we can talk about all the technical details.  The "but" is that there's a big surprise if you use `git commit --only`.  I seem to recall that there was a time when it affected `git commit -a` badly too, but it's better about that now.  (I'm not sure which Git versions behave badly with `-a`.)

#### Long

Git makes each new commit from an—or *the*, in most cases—index.  The index, or any index, is essentially a proposed commit: it consists of a sort of flattened tree, with blob hash numbers and file names.  It's in a form that makes it especially convenient for `git mktree`, which turns the index into a series of *tree* objects and returns the hash ID of the top level tree object, which then goes into the commit object.

The question, then, touches on these three parts:

1. Precisely *which* index is being used to build the new commit?
2. Can that index be modified?  If so, what happens to the new commit?
3. How does this affect *the* index?

Here, *the* index is the special, distinguished index that goes with the work-tree.  There is one such index per work-tree: if you use `git worktree add` you get more work-trees, and each one gets its own private index, but you're only ever *in* one work-tree at a time, so "this work-tree's index" is *the* index.

However, when you run `git commit`, you can instruct it (using `--only` and/or other command line arguments) to build its own *private* index, separate from *the* index.  If you have done so, it will run each of the various hooks with an environment variable, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, set to the path name of the temporary index.  (If not, `GIT_INDEX_FILE` will contain `.git/index`, which is the path to *the* index file.)

So the answer to Q1 is: `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`.

Now, you can in fact modify whichever index Git is using to build the commit, because Git will re-read this index after running your hooks.  So the answer to Q2 is: Yes, and this makes the next commit use whatever's in whichever index is in use.

Q3 is the hardest.  If you use `git commit --only <paths>`, Git must make a temporary index that:

- is a copy of `HEAD`
- except for the specified `<paths>`

without disturbing *the* index at all.  If the commit goes on and succeeds, though, Git must now modify *the* index to account for the fact that these `<paths>` have new blobs in them in the new `HEAD` commit.

In fact, Git needs to make *two* temporary indexes (indices?), one for the proposed commit with its `--only` files, and one for the proposed commit result.  The proposed commit result becomes `index.lock`, which acts as the new index.

If you `git add` files while running, they will go into the temporary index.  But what about *the* index?  Let's find out:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#! /bin/sh
echo pre-commit hook, GIT_INDEX_FILE = $GIT_INDEX_FILE
git add sneaky
$ echo this is the base version of sneaky > sneaky
$ echo this is the base version of other > other
$ git add other sneaky
$ git commit -m 'create two files'
pre-commit hook, GIT_INDEX_FILE = .git/index
[master 5131b63] create two files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 other
 create mode 100644 sneaky
```

As you can see, the pre-commit hook fired here, and added `sneaky`.  This is no big deal since what got copied into the index for this commit—which is *the* index—was already that same base version.

Now, however, let's modify the current contents of `sneaky`, `git add` it, and also modify the current contents of `other`, and `git add` it, so that we have new contents in *the* index for both files...

```
$ echo version 2 of other > other
$ echo version 2 of sneaky > sneaky
$ git add other sneaky
```

At this point, both index and work-tree have "version 2".  Now let's update both work-tree files to "version 3" *without* `git add`ing them:

```
$ echo version 3 of other > other
$ echo version 3 of sneaky > sneaky
$ git status --short
MM other
MM sneaky
```

This tells us that the `HEAD`, index, and work-tree versions all differ: the `HEAD` version of each is the base, the index version is version 2, and the work-tree version is version 3.

Now we run `git commit --only other`:

```
$ git commit --only other -m 'jump other straight to v3'
pre-commit hook, GIT_INDEX_FILE = [path]/.git/next-index-72393.lock
[master 91ec03b] jump other straight to v3
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Let's see what we have in the commit, the index, and the work-tree now:

```
$ git status --short
MM sneaky
```

OK, the work-tree version of `other` matches the index version of `other` which matches the `HEAD` version of `other`, so:

```
$ cat other
version 3 of other
```

they are all version 3.  What about `sneaky`, though?  The `HEAD` and index differ, and the index and the work-tree differ.  Let's see what's in `HEAD` first:

```
$ git show HEAD:sneaky
version 3 of sneaky
```

Now let's see what's in the work-tree:

```
$ cat sneaky
version 3 of sneaky
```

Aha, these match!  The tricky part is viewing the index version, but we can do that too with `git show`:

```
$ git show :0:sneaky
version 2 of sneaky
```

Whoa, look at that!  *The* index version is the old one!

This, then, is the answer to Q3: the `git add` in the pre-commit hook updates whichever index is being used to build the next commit, but if that's a *temporary* index, it *does not* update what will become the real index.  This is arguably a bug: `git add` in the pre-commit hook should also add to the index that will become *the* index.  Making that happen is a little tricky (`git commit` could read the temporary index before and after the hook and copy any updates to the index.lock file, perhaps).

Note that I skipped the details for what happens if you commit without `--only`.  Fortunately, in this case the index you add to is *the* index, so everything works as you would expect:

```
$ git reset --hard 5131b63
HEAD is now at 5131b63 create two files
$ echo v2 > other && echo v2 > sneaky && git add other
$ git commit -m 'regular commit'
pre-commit hook, GIT_INDEX_FILE = .git/index
[master 10a8b20] regular commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
$ git status --short
$
```

The pre-commit `git add` replaced the index version of `sneaky`, and it stayed replaced ... which it will even if the commit *fails*.

Note also that when using `git commit -a`, we get a different temporary index:

```
$ git commit -a -m test
pre-commit hook, GIT_INDEX_FILE = [path]/.git/index.lock
```

Here, what Git does for `git commit -a` is to create the proposed new index *as* the `index.lock` file.  The `git add` proceeds normally, adding the file in the usual way, and then when the commit succeeds, Git *renames* `index.lock` to `index`.  This unlocks the index file and, at the same time, puts the modified index in place, so that the answer for `git commit -a` to Q3 is that the temporary index becomes the index.  This is different from that for `git commit --only`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831536/can-you-change-a-file-content-during-git-commit).

You want to use `.gitattributes` and specify scripts that run at add time (i.e. `git add`). This way, every time your file gets added, the script runs and makes the changes, then commits it.

Hope that helps!